# map and apply in java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I currently have something like below

```
List<String> myNewList = myList
                           .stream()
                           .map(item->{
                             return mappedItem
                           })
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
repository.save(myNewList);
```

In Optional, I can perform operations on the mapped item by using ifPresent method like below

```
myOptional
  .map(item -> {
    return mappedItem
  })
  .ifPresent(newItem -> {
    repository.save(newItem);
  });
```

I was wondering if I can do something like the above on stream. Rather than declaring `myNewList`, is there a way I can collect the new `List` and apply my function on the new list?

Update: Based on the answer from @tagir-valeev, I modified my code as below

```
myList
  .stream()
  .map(item->{
    return mappedItem
  })
  .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
    list -> {
      repository.save(list);
      return list;
    }
  ));
```

Comment: What's the point? If you don't want the `myNewList` variable, just pass the full stream statement to `save`.

Comment: Well, the `myOptional` way seem to be lot cleaner. Wrapping the entire stream statements within another function will make the code look more complicated.

Comment: You are essentially creating a new list filled with one identical item. Is that really what you want? Also `item-> { return mappedItem; }` is the same a `item-> mappedItem`...

Comment: @assylias thanks, `return mappedItem` is just a reference. In my original code, I have set of statements to determine new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your custom collector like this:

```
myList.stream().map(..)
      .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), repository::save));
```

If `save` return type is `void`, it would be more ugly as you need to return something from `collect`:

```
myList.stream().map(..)
      .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
              list -> {repository.save(list);return list;}));
```

You may declare special method in your `Repository` class:

```
class Repository {
    Collector<MyItemType, ?, List<MyItemType>> saving() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
              list -> {this.save(list);return list;});
    }

    void save(List<MyItemType> list) { ... }
}
```

And use it:

```
myList.stream().map(..).collect(repository.saving());
```

Comment: I was looking for collectingAndThen. Thanks for the answer.